# Can an entire drop down list be passed between pages using asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to pass the entire content of a drop down list between aspx pages?

I am working on a project which will have multiple web forms of data entry, but the first few items are the same fields each time. I can easily re-select the fields during the page load, but this would require posting to the server every time, and I would like to avoid doing so if possible. My drop lists contain real world descriptions (such as the name of a part) as the text of each item and the SQL sever primary keys as each value. Because of this, I need to pass both the items' text and their values.

```
protected DropDownList PopulateList(String sqlCommand, String itemText, String itemValue, DropDownList ddlID)
   {
        // creation of the connection string, command statement, and data reader
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdiMfgData"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        try
        {
            ListItem newItem = new ListItem();
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // list population
                newItem = new ListItem();
                newItem.Text = reader[itemText].ToString();
                newItem.Value = reader[itemValue].ToString();
                ddlID.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err) { }
        connection.Close();
        return ddlID;
    }
```

If it helps, here is the method used to populate lists with the needed items. THIS IS WORKING WHEN NOT TRYING TO MAINTAIN DROP DOWN LIST ITEMS ACROSS PAGES. However, I cannot figure out how to pass the populated list to another page.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972429(v=msdn.10)

Comment: You could store it in the session, you could store it in the cache, there are a number of ways to tackle this.